# Spike detection and removal in position data

Tags: outliers, smoothing, signal-processing

Is there any good filter to remove big spikes in position data? I think lowpass filter should be good but is it possible to filter 2D position data with assumption its joint distributed? I mean, not using LPF on the one dimension and on the second dimension separately.

My data looks like data from gps. A object is moving in x and y coordinates. A sensor has hw error. When the sensor touches a metal thing it returns the position very far from the real position. When you look at as a track on map its jump very far from real position and jump back near to real position.

Comment: Can you add some context here? I'm not sure your question is answerable at present. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your goals?

Comment: Check my edit. There is more description of my problem.

Comment: That probably helps (I don't know anything about GPS data). You'll want to spell out your acronyms. Eg, what is "hw error"?

Comment: @gung presumably "hardware" but OP will need to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 2D Fourier transformation and remove all frequencies above some threshold. Spikes should correspond to relatively high frequencies.

Doing Fourier decomposition in 2D is essentially done in two steps: first in one direction, then on second direction (on processed data). The software packages (e.g. in MATLAB) do this pretty efficiently.

Comment: I tried it. I used FFT to check frequences to cut. But if I cut lower frequencies I lose so much information. Median filter works much better.